# What is the most effective way to compare, find and return a large set of mobile numbers while identifying contacts?

Tags: sql, django, search, registration, django-rest-framework

Say I have data for 1000 users on my DB and someone new signs up. I want them to have an easy to way find contacts already registered - via their phone number. Something very similar to WhatsApp, Allo, Instagram, Twitter etc. do - they allow you to see what contacts are already using their services.

The DB stores usernames and contact information - name, number etc. If X signs up with 200 contacts, do I compare each of the 200 with each of the 1000 existing?

Surely, there's a better way than taking my New User's 200 contacts and comparing each one to the existing 1000 records. How do the other services manage this? Is there a specific sort of data structure I should be maintaining for searching?

Will a tree or graph structure be a more efficient approach in this scenario? If so, how should I be implementing it?

I'm using DRF for the back-end implementation.

I've searched around, but I don't seem to find a good answer for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your content is in a database. You aren't required to work out the most efficient data structures to use to store the information; your database engine already does that. And it does it way better than you ever could. (That's not a personal insult; databases store and retrieve information way better than ANYONE could.)

Ultimately, you do need to compare each of the 200 new numbers against each of the 1,000 numbers in your database. You don't have to work out how to do that efficiently, though. Just ask the database if any of those numbers exist and it will (I guarantee) work out the most efficient possible way to do it.

For a database with many millions of records, the answer to the question "Does this value already exist?" should still come back in the tiniest fraction of a second.